# Plotting data with exponentials

Tags: import, data-format

I have some data with 19000 sublists such as :

```
{"   7.9080000e+01   1.9283193e+04"}
```

Where the first number is the value for variable `A` and the second for variable `B`.

All my attempts to transform this format have failed so far. I think my best guess was using `ToExpression` unsuccessfully.

How can I transform such lists to a "plottable" format by

- Changing the `String` format ?
- Computing the `e` ?
- Import the data differently ?

Comment: How did you import this data?  `Import` supports this (very common) number format: `ImportString["12e3", "Table"]`

Comment: Can you test Andy Ross and Mr Wizard solutions on your real world problem and see which is faster and post?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to use `ReadList` on the string contents of each sublist. Here I'm just creating a small list containing three elements identical to the one you provided. The result can be plotted using ListPlot for example.

```
In[20]:= in = {{"   7.9080000e+01   1.9283193e+04"}, 
               {"   7.9080000e+01   1.9283193e+04"}, 
               {"   7.9080000e+01   1.9283193e+04"}};

In[22]:= Table[ReadList[StringToStream@First[i], Number], {i, in}]

Out[22]= {{79.08, 19283.2}, {79.08, 19283.2}, {79.08, 19283.2}}
```

**EDIT:**

Due to the comments I should point out that this `Table` is going to produce an array that is not packed.  This means that the evaluator isn't aware ahead of time that all of the values are a particular type (namely real in this case) and so it is going to lean toward more general methods and is going to consume more memory to store the table.

As the documentation for `` Developer`ToPackedArray `` points out, using `` Developer`ToPackedArray `` will not change results generated by Mathematica, but can enhance speed of execution and reduce memory usage.

In order to pack the result we can simply use ruebenko's suggestion placing `` Developer`ToPackedArray@ `` in front of our `Table`.

**TESTING EDIT:**

I decided to test whether `ImportString` proposed by Mr. Wizard or the `ReadList` approach might be faster. In fairness I separated the `ExportString` out presuming that the string would already be saved somewhere for importing.  It appears that `ReadList` is much faster at least for the fabricated example I've created here.  I'd be curious to see if this is true for 500's data.

```
In[21]:= data = Table["   7.9080000e+01   1.9283193e+04", {5000}];

In[22]:= Export["numbers.txt", data];

In[23]:= in = Partition[ReadList[StringToStream@Import["numbers.txt", 
              "Plaintext"], Record], 1];

In[24]:= (andyr = Table[ReadList[StringToStream@First[i], Number]
                   , {i, in}]); // AbsoluteTiming

Out[24]= {0.0780015, Null}

In[25]:= str = ExportString[in, "Table"];

In[26]:= (mrwiz = ImportString[str, "Table"]); // AbsoluteTiming

Out[26]= {4.1340795, Null}

In[27]:= andyr === mrwiz

Out[27]= True
```

I should also point out that this comparison is only fair if we assume that the data is already in memory.  If not, the cost for Importing should be factored in to the `ReadList` approach.

Comment: You may want to add a couple of Developer`ToPackedArray@ in front of ReadList and Table.

Comment: @ruebenko, true. But, why would a novice want to do that?

Comment: @rcollyer, because he has 19000 sublists....

Comment: @ruebenko, I was trying to get you to explain what a packed array is and does for you.

Comment: @rcollyer, misunderstood that. The reason is that the OP would possibly benefit from less memory being consumed and a possibly speedier consumption of subsequent commands.

Comment: +1 for the fast method and full explanation; Since I saw this problem as a matter of incorrect initial importing, I also saw this as a one-time or rare event, and I answered with what I believe is the easiest to remember, most direct and logical "fix" for the problem after the fact.

Comment: @Andy, if you have a minute, could you tell me if you manage to import/transform then export a .dat with those data ? Its is a csv file. For some reason, after transformation my .nb is suffering a lot : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20775208/Sparrow/4cc1fc0419535e2fd6b2dd1276e9f5e1/data1.csv

Comment: @500 it works if you replace the first two steps with the following two steps. `data = Import["data1.csv"];` Followed by `Export["numbers.txt", Flatten@data]`. Then just proceed with the above approach.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard this question came up recently for me when dealing with a custom file format of mine. With out knowing the length of the data section (an oversight in the format :P), it is often easier to read each line in as a string and process from there. So, it isn't necessarily a one time problem, unfortunately.

Comment: @AndyRoss doesn't the stream created by `StringToStream` have to be closed?

Comment: @rcollyer yes that would be a good idea. I get lazy sometimes and let the closing of M do it for me. In practice you should definitely close it.

Comment: That brings up a good point, when does M close it for you?

Comment: @rcollyer I believe when the kernel quits the stream is closed.

Comment: @AndyRoss here's a [cautionary tale](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/XcK_fkeTQY0/discussion) of why you should close the streams. Incidentally, I discovered that I was running into the same issue last night: ~31k streams open! A rather "creative" way to bring my system to a halt. :)

Comment: @rcollyer this is good to know. In practice I always do but it is good to see a concrete example for why one should.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

As Szabolcs points out, this may be imported by `Import`. Here's one way to discover this: assign `expr = "   7.9080000e+01   1.9283193e+04"`, then use `ImportString` on it with all possible import formats, discard those that return `$Failed`, and look at the results:

```
Grid[
 DeleteCases[
  Quiet[{#, ImportString[expr, #]}] & /@ $ImportFormats,
  x_List /; (Last[x] == $Failed)
  ],
 Frame -> All
]
```

(you need `Quiet` because many of the `$ImportFormats` choke on this string). This produces a long table, in which one finds this (somewhere in the middle):

[image]

So `Import[file,"Table"]` will probably work.

That I found this was easier than finding this information in the documentation is interesting!

Answer (score 7):

I echo Szabolcs's comment that you should probably have done this on acquisition, but now you could use this:

```
dat = {
   {"   7.9080000e+01   1.9283193e+04"},
   {"   7.9080000e+01   1.9283193e+04"},
   {"   7.9080000e+01   1.9283193e+04"}
   };

ImportString@ExportString[dat, "Table"]
```

> ```
> {{79.08, 19283.2}, {79.08, 19283.2}, {79.08, 19283.2}}
> ```

Comment: I interpreted the question as "which import format should I have used?" (which you do in fact answer)

Comment: @acl, and that was actually a better question :-) Makes everything easier !

Comment: @Mr Wizard thank You, While, as suggested, i am now acting on acquisition. ImportString@ExportString is really cool !

Comment: @acl I answered the actual question, which I believe was asking for a quick fix to the immediate problem.